# In a microservices architecture, what are the drawbacks of the API gateway passing the user's access token directly to the backend services?

Tags: .net, security

Sorry if duplicated, I have read some similar questions or articles, but I have not gotten a clear analysis or answer.

In our microservices architecture, we have a api gateway between front-end and backend services. The API Gateway performs authentication by verifying the access token included in the request, and if verified, calls the corresponding backend service.
However, we have some disagreements on how to handle the Access Token:

1. option 1, Some developers believe that passing the Access Token directly is better, as it will preserve the user context information (sub, claim, etc.).
2. option 2, On the other hand, some developers think it's better to regenerate a new token using the Client Credential approach， and user information can be passed to the backend through HTTP headers or similar means.

Personally, I like option 1 as it's more intuitive，and avoid losing user information.

I don't know which approach is used more commonly. Are there any drawbacks of option 1?